# Cannot assign elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anything wrong with this code, such as not assigning right or something? All the referenced IDs exist, the console logs it, but only `topbar.cw` is assigned. I think it might be assigned elsewhere as well, not sure. Also, I'm not even sure what this is. Is it an array, or a class, or a construct or what?

```
var topbar = {};
if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
topbar.cw=document.getElementById('contentWrapper');
topbar.tb=document.getElementById('topbar');
topbar.hd=document.getElementById('header');
topbar.sm=document.getElementById('storyMenu');
topbar.dd=document.getElementById('dropdown');
topbar.bc=document.getElementById('bodyContent');
topbar.sb=document.getElementById('sidebar');
topbar.mm=document.getElementById('mainMenu');
topbar.da=document.getElementById('displayArea');
console.log("fired when done loading");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps document.readyState is not equal to 'complete' -- you'd have to paste more code.

Comment: What does `console.log(topbar);` give?

Comment: A lot of your questions could be answered using your browsers debugger. Press F12 in most modern browsers to launch it, and try stepping through your code to see what gets ran, when, and what its output is.

Comment: @chovy that's not the case because he mentioned that topbar.cw is assigned. But yes, we need to see the html or more to give a definite answer.

Comment: he also said it could have been assigned somewhere else. Does the log print?

Comment: It prints out the string I specified above. if I log the topbar it shows that 5 functions (as expected) and cw are assigned, all the rest are null. @chovy, if readyState isn't complete, then why does it satisfy the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code:

```
> var topbar = {};
```

Assigns a new object to `topbar`

```
> if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
```

If the value of `document.readyState` is equivalent to the string 'complete', then:

```
>     topbar.cw = document.getElementById('contentWrapper');
```

Assign the result of the call on the RHS to the `cw` property of `topbar`. If such a property doesn't exist, it is created.

If there is and element with an id of *contentWrapper*, assign a reference to the `cw` property. If no element with an id of *contentWrapper* exists, a value of `null` will be assigned, since that's what [document.getElementById](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) is specified to return if it can't find a matching element.

```
>   topbar.tb = document.getElementById('topbar');
>   ...
>   console.log("fired when done loading");
```

Is the above message ever displayed in the console? Have you tried:

```
    console.log(topbar);
```

If not, try it. Report what you see.

Comment: Then all of the properties should be assigned and should either reference DOM elements or be set to `null`. Note that if the properties don't exist, attempting to access them will return `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: Yes, they are set to null. I should update my question, that is my problem. I did find a workaround, and as this is a tiddlywiki, it isn't really a general html answer. You did answer my question, which was what the code is actually doing.

Comment: If they are `null`, then at the time the code runs the elements don't exist in the document. If you are using XMLHttpRequest, it may be running asynchronously so this code might be being called at a time you don't expect (e.g. readyState is complete but whatever function adds the elements to the document hasn't run yet). Note that the elements might also have been created, but not added. Perhaps use `setTimeout` to run this code after a short delay and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it does add it dynamically. It doesn't exist without javascript. Thanks, I think this helps.